# Remove char if infront of word in vector of string

Tags: c++

I have a vector of strings with different chars infront of them. for example:

```
"Hello
(Hello
```

I want to remove the first occurrence of the char. So if there is a `"` or `(` before the word, I want it gone. My code so far is this.

```
void wash(std::vector<std::string> & data)
{
    std::string b_chars = "\"'("; //Before_chars
    std::string a_chars = "!?;,:.\"')"; //after_chars

    data.erase(std::remove_if(data.begin(), data.end(), [&b_chars](const char& c) {
        return data.find_first_of(b_chars) != std::string::npos;
    }), data.end());  
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove a single char or all special chars before your word?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @Milton, do you just want to remove the first occurrence of the char? Also what about a_chars ?

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is wrong - you should determine whether `c` is one of the offending characters, which is `b_chars.find(c) != std::string::npos`.

To iterate over the entire vector, you could go:

```
std::for_each(data.begin(),
              data.end(),
              [&b_chars](std::string& str)
              {
                  str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), 
                              str.end(), 
                              [&b_chars](const char& c) 
                                  {return b_chars.find(c) != std::string::npos;}),
               data.end());
              });
          }
```

But it makes sense to have a separate string-washing function and not limit yourself to vectors of strings (I didn't read your code properly because this is a more useful building block to start with):

```
void wash_string(std::string & s)
{
    static const std::string b_chars = "\"'("; //Before_chars
    static const std::string a_chars = "!?;,:.\"')"; //after_chars

    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), 
                           s.end(), 
                          [&b_chars](const char& c) 
                             {return b_chars.find(c) != std::string::npos;}), 
               s.end());  
}

void wash(std::vector<std::string> & data)
{
    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), wash_string);
}
```

Comment: Would you please tell me what is `c` paramenter in the lambda function?

Comment: It's a character in the string `data`. The function is called once for each character and should answer whether that character should be removed or not.

Comment: Sorry @molbdnilo, I've realised this code is not working because you aren't iterating over the string, but over the vector only.

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems with your code:

1. in you code you dont remove chars from a string but from a vector of string. You should iterate your vector and do the removal on each string.
2. As in molbdnilo answer, you need to change the condition of your lambda to find character inside the string of offending chars

   ```
   void wash(std::vector<std::string> & data)
   {
      std::string b_chars = "\"'("; //Before_chars
      std::string a_chars = "!?;,:.\"')"; //after_chars

      for (auto& str : data) {
          str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
                                 [&](const char &c) { return b_chars.find_first_of(c) != std::string::npos; }),
                  str.end());
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: The whole function could be written with a ````std::transfrom```` and a ````std::regex_replace```` in a Lambda as one statement. But there are always many many ways to do something

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove these the chars only before the first occurrence of a 'normal char':

```
for (vector<std::string>::iterator vt_it = data.begin(); vt_it<data.end(); ++vt_it)
    {
        std::string::iterator str_it = (*vt_it).begin();
        while (str_it != (*vt_it).end())
        {
            if ((b_chars).find((*str_it)) == std::string::npos)
                break;
            str_it++;
        }

        (*vt_it).erase ((*vt_it).begin(), str_it); 
    }
```

But if you want to remove all those chars:

```
for (vector<std::string>::iterator vt_it = data.begin(); vt_it<data.end(); ++vt_it)
    {
        (*vt_it).erase(
            std::remove_if(
                (*vt_it).begin(), 
                (*vt_it).end(), 
                [&b_chars](const char& c) {return b_chars.find(c) != std::string::npos;}),
            (*vt_it).end()
        );
    }
```

OBS. You didn't reffer anything about what you want to do with `a_chars`. I tested all the codes in these post, included mine.